# wordpress: echo after select database table

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I try to programm a plugin, which echo the number of data in a table:

```
...        
<form method="post" action="" id="fwhallowelt" class="validate">
<h2>Title</h2>


<?php echo 'test'; 

 $user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users" );
 echo "<p>{$user_count}</p>";

 ?>

 <br>
 <textarea name..........
```

It prints the "test" in my wp-backend, but nothing else. That means, everthing after my echo "test" will not be printed anymore. Any ideas?

Greets Yab86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pasted your code in my site and it works. Therefore, it seems to me that there is only one thing this could be, a scoping problem. Chances are, your code snippet lives inside a function, or inside a file that is included inside a function. This means that `$wpdb` is not in the current scope. My gut instinct here is that you need to add `global $wpdb;` above your sql statement, like this:

```
...        
<form method="post" action="" id="fwhallowelt" class="validate">
<h2>Title</h2>


<?php echo 'test'; 

////// ADD THIS LINE, HERE
global $wpdb;

$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users" );
echo "<p>{$user_count}</p>";

?>

<br>
<textarea name..........
```